# How to install infomap module in anaconda(python3.8) on win10?

Tags: python, linux, gcc, conda

I need to use the InfoMap module(https://github.com/mapequation/infomap) for graph clustering, installed with pip.

1.First,I installed a windows subsystem for Linux on Win10. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/wsl/install-win10#manual-installation-steps

2.Then installed pip and pip3 in Ubuntu.

```
sudo apt-get -y update
sudo apt-get install python3-pip
sudo apt-get install python-pip
```

3.Then installed `gcc` in Ubuntu.

```
sudo apt install gcc
```

4.Then installed infomap 1.3.0(https://pypi.org/project/infomap/) in Ubuntu.

```
pip install infomap
```

The infomap module was installed successfully, the path is:`/home/xc1996/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages (1.3.0)`

5.My anaconda modules packages path is `F:\Users\xc\anaconda3\Lib\site-packages` on Win10.
Now,my anaconda(python3.8) on win10 can't find this module.

6.In order to install it on my anaconda's path,i also tried

```
sudo pip3 install infomap --target=/mnt/f/Users/xc/anaconda3/Lib/site-packages
```

Now,my anaconda(python3.8) on win10 also can't find this module,don't know which step is wrong.How to install it correctly?

Comment: Was the environment activated when running the pip install? I'm not sure how WSL will impact this whole situation, though.

Comment: Which directory should add to PATH？I have never used Linux before, just follow the steps on above websites. I tried `echo 'export PATH=/home/xc1996/.local/bin:$PATH' >>~/.bashrc` `source ~/.bashrc` `pip3 uninstall infomap` `pip3 install infomap` to add to PATH, also doesn't work...

Comment: Or the infomap module can only be run in ubuntu? i don't know...

Comment: If you only need the CLI, Conda Forge builds it, so `conda install conda-forge::infomap`. That, however, will not include the Python API. Otherwise, you really need to use the `pip` in Conda, not a system-level one.

Answer (score 0):

You are saying that you need to use infomap module present in github.com

```
1]First install git in your PC.  
2]go to the link     *https://github.com/mapequation/infomap*  
3]on the github page copy this link in code button or copy the below       link  
4]the link is this *https://github.com/mapequation/infomap.git*  
5]copy the above link  
6]open the cmd in your windows and type the below command  
7]git clone *https://github.com/mapequation/infomap.git*  
8]You are done
```

Comment: Thank you for your method, I have successfully installed and run in the Linux subsystem for win10, and your method is still very useful.